# Accidentally bought stock without cash to cover

Tags: stocks, mistakes

I accidentally bought a stock in the wrong account. I don't have the money to cover it. Can I sell it same day to get out of it, or, what do I do?

My other account is TFSA so I don't want to transfer money over and I don't have any other cash to cover it.

Comment: What kind of account did you buy it in? A cash account or a margin account?

Comment: I think a cash account

Comment: It's possible it's margin... trying to figure that out

Comment: Got through to the bank. Not sure how much help it was. They said because the balance is positive (after I sold back the stock) it will be fine. Maybe it's that simple?

Comment: If you bought stock without enough money to cover it then it must have been a margin account; unless this broker employed some really terrible programmers. The other thought is that you don't have enough "settled" funds to cover the transaction. If this is the case then you likely used unsettled funds to make the purchase but now should wait till your funds clear before selling or else you will trigger a good faith violation.

Answer (score 4):

Selling the stock today might make the problem worse. It might result in a [good faith violation, freeriding violation or cash liquidation violation](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/trading-investing/trading/avoiding-cash-trading-violations), which might result in a temporary restriction being placed on your account.

Call your brokerage on the phone and ask them what to do.

If you *already* sold the stock, and your account now has a credit balance (that is, a positive balance) in cash, I can't think of anything further that you can do to make the situation better.

Comment: You know, it sounds like for the OP, it is very unlikely that a temporary trading restriction would be a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Australia at least you buy & sell all through the day and owe (or are owed) your end-of-day net after T+2 days.  So "yes" if your broker has allowed you credit to buy without a balance in your trading cash account. Any obligation is between you and your broker and whatever terms they gave you.

After 14 hours, I am guessing this answer is now irrelevant though.